# Storing front end third party API keys in redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern, api-key

Building a full stack MERN (Mongo Express React Node) application.  I am using redux to manage app level state. I am considering storing my front end third party API keys in the redux state.

Pseudo code is a follows

- User visits site call is used GET request is made to API
- GET request queriers keys from my my database
- Data is stored in the redux application state

Concerns

- Redux state is not secure and can be accessed by users

My two questions are

- is this an secure practice?
- if this is not secure could you direct me to information to implement storage of front end third party API keys

Thank you for your time and thoughts

Comment: You can proxy the request to your server if you don't want users to see the api key and have the api key on your server.

Comment: @HMR thanks for the advice.  For anyone who is interested the article posted below provides an architectural guide for setting up a proxy request.  https://unicorn-utterances.com/posts/keeping-api-keys-secret-in-react-apps/?utm_content=buffer9993e&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer